# Using an external JS file in razor to create div

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working in Mvc4. I have added an external JS inside my project, and written a loop inside that JS. Is it possible to create a certain number of divs in my index view page using that external JS?

Comment: to answer your question: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible, the question is where you want to insert it. inside the view? the layout? under the body? under the form?

But generally speaking, yes of course you can.

Comment: Inside the view. Can you please explain that to create the divs how i can use the external JS? Do i need to use razor for that?

Comment: You do not need razor, if you are writing the javascript on your on, there are two ways: first: you can add <src></src> calling to your external javascript and then use it on your view. the second thing is to define it inside the script bundles, so It will become globally contained within all your default js files.